# JMeter: "Response code: 500, Response message: Internal Server Error" in Sampler Result

Tags: performance, testing, server, jmeter, response

I am extracting all dynamic values of my asp.net Website dynamically however, I can see "Response code: 500, Response message: Internal Server Error" in Sampler Result.

Below is the Request from View Results in a Tree:

```html
POST http://MyURL/MyPortal/login.aspx

POST data:
__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMTI3MjAzNjAzNGRkjr4joFF5LWOOmI2LfqKYaLCnJoWEEuersumW%2Fyg8oSE%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAe%2FZNCyf7CfdyOuzLZ7mDoL9Tt6KoVd96dN6zOjIKoOlInkg%2Fut7Je4AtoEsfzZAOLszNp1xh91HdjgSkSmA8AOAmWyFUPYYwjYUgZAnHgtx2Vqz9dZFL0pGDKPfgeuicZtnfqjBya34OcE2Eru6nT4MwnrIcmty4bwVAU6VEb6qrGc%2BEe7Y58My78ZHzJqq0k%3D&txtUserID=1111111&txtPWD=ASDF&BtnSubmit=Submit&hdnE=5&hdnN=323&hdnD=173

Cookie Data:
ASP.NET_SessionId=e0ibh0ihceof54ulvhkx1

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://MyURL/MyPortal/login.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Length: 386
```

And, Response Code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Runtime Error</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/MyPortal' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
            <br><br>

            <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
    &lt;system.web&gt;
        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
    &lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application&#39;s &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
    &lt;system.web&gt;
        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;
    &lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you correlated `VIEWSTATE` and `EVENTVALIDATION` parameters? If not - you cannot have them hard-coded. You need to design your test case as follows:

- GET Request to login page (user opens login page)

  - Extract "VIEWSTATE", "EVENTVALIDATION" and any other dynamic parameters into JMeter Variables
- POST Request to login page (user enters credentials)

  - Provide previously extracted "VIEWSTATE" and "EVENTVALIDATION" variables values, login, password and any other parameters.

Depending on your skills and nature of response you can use the following Post Processors in order to extract dynamic values:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) (also read [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

You can also see [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for end-to-end steps on bypassing login challenge in ASP.NET applications in JMeter.

Comment: Yes, I am extracting values for both using CSS/jquery extractor. Also, this error appears even if single user is used to login.

Comment: Use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to ensure that JMeter sends the same request details as browser does. Also it worth checking with developers actual error details as currently the real reason is hidden.

Comment: Well, Values for both __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION remains static for every login i.e:

__VIEWSTATE: /wEPDwUKMTI3MjAzNjAzNGRkjr4joFF5LWOOmI2LfqKYaLCnJoWEEuersumW/yg8oSE=

__EVENTVALIDATION: wEdAAe/ZNCyf7CfdyOuzLZ7mDoL9Tt6KoVd96dN6zOjIKoOlInkg/ut7Je4AtoEsfzZAOLszNp1xh91HdjgSkSmA8AOAmWyFUPYYwjYUgZAnHgtx2Vqz9dZFL0pGDKPfgeuicZtnfqjBya34OcE2Eru6nT4MwnrIcmty4bwVAU6VEb6qrGc+Ee7Y58My78ZHzJqq0k=

And in Response Code, I am not able to debug as there is no "Login" in Text in View Results in a Tree.
And for "RegExp Testing", Match found 0.

Please check screenshot I ahve just added in Query.

Comment: They shouldn't be the same as far as i understand the technology. Screenshots of error page are useless, make a GET request to login page and post somewhere the output

Comment: Well, Strange but its static. However, thanks for the reply, that was helpful.